# « encore » et « toujours » sont-ils sémantiquement interchangeables ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adverbes

J'amerais savoir si *encore* et *toujours*, qui tous les deux signifie en anglais *up to this time*, sont dans tous les contextes interchangeables.

Comment: Pas encore… heu, pas toujours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non. Un dictionnaire donnera plus de détails que moi, mais grosso modo, *« toujours »* et *« encore »* peuvent correspondre au *« still »* anglais, mais *« toujours »* peut également signifier *« always »* (parmi d’autres) alors que *« encore »* se traduira plutôt par *« again »* ou *« more »* (dans *« Do you want more wine? »*). *« Pas encore »* signifiera quant à lui *« not yet »*, sens que n’a pas *« pas toujours »*.