# J'attends toujours ma commande - meaning of toujours

Tags: adverbes

I have recently seen the sentence:

> J'attends toujours ma commande

As "toujours" can mean "always" or "still, can that sentence mean "I always wait for my order" and "I am still waiting for my order" ?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/encore-et-toujours-sont-ils-s%c3%a9mantiquement-interchangeables and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/toujours-vs-encore-to-translate-still

Answer (score 6):

With the right context this sentence can have both meanings, but without context I'd understand it as "*I'm still waiting for my order.*"

It's not *that* common to talk about your waiting habits for a specific restaurant. Also, you'd have add something to say *where*. "*Dans ce restau, j'attends toujours ma commande.*"

---

Btw, there's nothing wrong about it grammatically, but I don't see why you'd need to say "*I always wait for my order*". Don't you always, at least a little? *I always wait* has to imply "*I always wait too long*" for the sentence to have meaning.

But the grammatical point still holds, and it might be more ambiguous with different sentences. For instance:

> Je cherche toujours à donner un sens à ce que je fais.

Can mean "*Quand je fais quelque chose, j'essaie de lui donner du sens*" and "*Je cherche un sens à ce que je fais, et je n'en ai toujours pas trouvé*", and it's hard to tell without context.

Answer (score 5):

Without further context, grammatically it can mean both. The first idea that comes to mind is probably `still waiting` but it could mean `always waiting`.

We don't even need to add `longtemps`, `pendant des heures` or any duration, as it would be understood:

> A: Et si on allait manger Chez Marcel ce midi ?
>
> B: Oh non ! Je n'aime pas ce resto, on attend toujours notre commande !

Comment: Quelle partie ne vous paraît pas claire ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "toujours" meaning "always", and meaning "still".

J'attends toujours....

It means you are still waiting. The action goes on.

J'attends toujours ma commande.
Is the same.

"Je fais toujours l'idiot"
Means that you play the fool always (or rather in some contexts, "usually", or "often", as it's an euphemistic use.)

It depends the kind of verb. If you use "toujours" with "attendre", it means that the actions is still going on, doesn't stop.

If you have an action that can be repeated, it means "always", if the action is lasting, it means "still".

Il n'est toujours pas là = still.

It's sometimes a context thing:

Elle parle toujours:

-Elle parle *toujours* du beau temps. (always)
-Je me suis endormi, et elle parle *toujours*. (still)

But observe that the "toujours" here is not at the same place in these sentences.

When «toujours» (or «encore») is at the end of the sentence (or clause), it's a "still".

Il vit encore = il vit toujours. = Still living.

But the reverse is not true, not all "still" meaning are at the end: Je vis toujours chez mes parents = still.
But here, in this sentence, it's obvious, you cannot "live often", or several times as a repeated action.

It really depends on the verb, if it can be a repeated action, or an ongoing action.

"I always wait for my order" = Habituellement/D'habitude/Généralement/En général (etc...), j'attends longuement ma commande/ J'ai à attendre longuement ma commande/On me fait attendre longtemps ma commande, etc...

The English "always" doesn't mean 100% always here, but rather an habit, so you can express it any way of the normal French habits expressions.

Comment: Your last 2 lines might address this, but the only way that I interpret "I always wait for my order" in English is to mean (in describing how someone always/usually/repeatedly gets their prescriptions filled at pharmacies, for example): "I always place my order & wait until it's ready" (as opposed to "I always drop off my order & return later to pick it up"); where there's no feeling of frustration about the wait being long. (to clearly convey the frustrated, "long-wait" meaning, again in English, I would feel the need to add "have to": "I always *have to* wait for my order [at that place].")

Answer (score 0):

Il faut prendre en considération la conjugaison du verbe pour comprendre la phrase. Les temps servent à indiquer à quel moment se déroule une action.

- La phrase « J'attends toujours ma commande » *peut avoir* de multiples significations : c'est-à-dire que le sens d'un propos peut également être moins compréhensible ou moins pertinent par rapport aux situations ou selon les personnes.
- Cette réponse part du principe que la phrase est dite de façon pertinente, quelle que soit la situation.

La phrase « J'attends toujours ma commande » signifie que la personne ***attend*** **tout le temps qu'il faudra**, jusqu'à que sa commande soit arrivée (**ou tout le temps qu'il faut**) *ou alors* que la commande ***prend*** *beaucoup de temps* à arriver (la personne patiente depuis longtemps).

**TLDR;**

***On ne dira pas*** « J'attends toujours longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant » parce que **la durée de l'action n'est pas forcément immuable** ¹. Ne pas confondre une action finie ou prévisible avec une action en cours (voir l'exemple ci-dessous).

> **Je prends toujours** beaucoup de temps **avant de** me décider, et **quand enfin** je me décide c'est souvent trop tard.

On aurait dit « J'**ai** toujours **attendu** longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant » pour dire que la commande **prenait *chaque fois*** beaucoup de temps à arriver.

- Vous pouvez [constater que](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attendre+longtemps%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1994,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=4WPrXbusEoGFjLsPtaGwQA&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwj7oLKmkKPmAhWBAmMBHbUQDAg4HhDy0wMILg&biw=1296&bih=607&dpr=1) « attendre longtemps » est principalement conjugué au passé. C'est conjugué au présent ou au futur mais avec des verbes comme *devoir*, *aller*, *pouvoir*.

***On ne dira pas*** « J'ai toujours à attendre longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant ».

---

¹ <sub>ou pour paraphraser [le CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toujours) : « l'étendue de durée est déterminée par le temps grammatical ».</sub>

Comment: Aucune règle n'interdit de dire « J'attends toujours longtemps ...»: [*J'attends toujours longtemps le bassin, et quand enfin on me le passe, c'est souvent trop tard.*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=E9IMM2hTLA4C&lpg=PT110&dq=%22J'attends%20toujours%20longtemps%22&hl=fr&pg=PT110#v=onepage&q=j'attends%20toujours%20longtemps&f=false), *C'est pareil pour moi, j'attends toujours longtemps avant d'aller chez le coiffeur et à la fin c'est insoutenable*, *Quand je traverse avec mes deux enfants, j'attends toujours longtemps après que le feu pour piéton soit passé au vert.*

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec le premier paragraphe mais pas les "on ne peut pas dire".

Comment: Désolé, mais remplacer *on ne peut pas dire* par *on ne dira pas* ne change pas vraiment le sens qui reste prescriptiviste.

Answer (score -1):

It means "I am still waiting for my order"

Comment: So how would you say "I always wait (a lot) for my order (in this restaurant)" in French ?

Comment: "J'attends toujours longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant"

Comment: Based on your last answer, I do not understand why "toujours" cannot mean "always" in my original example.

Comment: "J'attends toujours longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant" is not too good but will do. Clearer : "J'ai toujours à attendre longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant." or "Il faut toujours que j'attende longtemps ma commande dans ce restaurant.".

Comment: I think it's not grammatically wrong to say "J'attends toujours longtemps", but it sounds weird, and awkward, I agree with LPH

Comment: Je pense que cette réponse devrait être un peu plus étoffée, peut-être avec des exemples ou davantage d'explications pour aider l'OP, elle est un peu courte.

Comment: Downvoted. It's misleading to say "it means", like there is no doubt. Grammatically it can mean "still" or "always", we cannot know for sure without further context. It's even very common to say "j'attends" with the idea of "j'attends longtemps", so it could totally mean "I always wait (a lot)".